# How to calculate the register draught/draft loss (RDL) of a burner?

Tags: pressure, power-engineering

I am aware this is a vague question but it is something which has been on my mind.

Would anybody know the steps used to calculate the draught loss across a burner in the furnace of a boiler?

Would it involve using parameters from the forced or induced draft fan?

What other values would need to be taken into consideration?

Thanks!

Comment: Any regulations set by anyone? they would normally specify the measuring constraints / methods... And would this be country / location specific?

Comment: Location is Greater China but I do not believe there are specific regulations set. I would just like some guidance on the steps required to calculate the register draft loss .